# Why learning rate needs to be decreased when the loss remains constant for epochs?

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent

Any intuitive explanation on why learning rate needs to be decreased when the loss remains constant for epochs?. Will this method not make the network get stuck in local minima or a plateau?

Answer (score 2):

What helped me understanding it was to assume that my loss function depends only on a single feature. Therefore, it could be something like a parabola. Now imagine that you are on the branch on the left side of the minimum. If you choose the learning rate too big, this could cause you to step over the minimum and you end up on the right branch. If you repeat this, you keep alternating between points on both branches without reaching the minimum. BUT: If you decrease your learning rate now, you slowly get closer the real minimum.

That means: if your cost remains relatively constant over some time, it could be that you step over a local minimum. Therefore you can try to decrease your steps.

And yes: you generally only find local minima with most methods. As you normally have multivariate cost functions, you randomly start somewhere and you try to find some kind of minimum. As you normally do several runs, it is likely that you end up with different local minima.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what if thats a long saddle point or a valley, if we keep constantly decreasing the learning rate will it not prevent the network getting out of saddle points or valleys?

Comment: Saddle points are usually not a problem as you have to imagine a cost function of hundreds of parameters. It is very unlikely to get stuck in a saddle point in higher dimensions. Also, the reason to decrease the step size IS to get stuck in valleys and find their minimum.

Comment: Thanks for your response :)